Windows event log not showing process crash
What could be preventing a process crash from not being recorded in the Windows event log? Specifically, Google Chrome shows there was a crash recorded in chrome://crashes/, but the Windows Event Viewer shows no Application Error events in Windows Logs\Application , with no filters turned on. Shortly afterward, I got the following program to log a crash event:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int* p = (int*)456789;
    *p = 1;
    return 0;
}

to verify the log service is running.

well, it sounds like Chrome is acting as the runtime, handling the exception, and letting the application close gracefully, such that windows doesn't see it as a crash per se. most programming runtimes provide a means to handle exceptions and prevent an actual crash.
